# Angle between 2 lines with each line represented by set of lat/lon pairs

Tags: java, geotools

I'm really new to GIS and i'm interested in finding angle between 2 lines. Each line is represented by start location(lat/lon) and end location(lat/lon).

Could some one point to an algorithm or any sample code(in any language), I can port that in to my desired language?

I tried searching in different forums but all i found was distance between 2 points and distance between a point and line, but not one to find the angle.

Comment: Somewhere in these [search results](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=angle+between+two+lines) there should be an answer.

Comment: It looks more like a trigonometry problem than a GIS problem, maybe have a look on this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327253/how-do-we-find-out-angle-from-x-y-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) provides a [`GeodeticCalculator`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html) for this sort of calculation, so something like this should solve your problem:

```
DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
Point point1 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(0,0));//GenerateRandomData.createRandomPoint();
calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(point1.getX(), point1.getY());

Point point2 =gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(10,10));// GenerateRandomData.createRandomPoint();
calc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(point2.getX(), point2.getY());


double azimuth1 = calc.getAzimuth();
System.out.println("Azimuth1 "+point1+", "+point2+" is "+ azimuth1);


Point point3 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(10,-10));//GenerateRandomData.createRandomPoint();
calc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(point3.getX(), point3.getY());

double azimuth2 = calc.getAzimuth();
System.out.println("Azimuth1 "+point1+", "+point3+" is "+ azimuth2);

System.out.println("Angle is "+(azimuth2-azimuth1));
```